# Fedora nfs mount disappears

Tags: linux, nfs, fedora

I have a small host running Fedora 18 (3.6.11), with nfs server set to serve /mnt/dir.

The problem on the client running Fedora (3.11.6) after just a minute or so the mount disappears. SELinux is disabled on both host and client, and I am able to see the nfs mount on client and both read and write to it. But after a few seconds to a minute it dissapears.

-------/etc/fsttab entry-----

```
my-serv:/mnt/dir /mnt/share/  nfs4 rw,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr,hard 0 0
```

After mount -a,

```
  $ ls -l /mnt/share/ 
    -rw-r--r--  1 root     root         0 Jun 22 05:50 test
    ......
```

a few moments later,

```
    $ ls -l /mnt/netshare/
    total 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So appears, by using autofs I am able to resolve the nfs mount from disappearing. Removing the fstab entry and adding the following to /etc/auto.master and /etc/atuo.misc per Fedora docs.

---/etc/auto.master----

> /mnt /etc/auto.misc

----/etc/auto.misc----

```
share/  -fstype=ext3 rw,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr my-serv:/mnt/dir
```